Как использовать объект Bot в aiмogram Python В отдельном файле router с другими handlers
У меня проблема, хочу изменить сообщение в боте aiogram3 Python Но для этого нужно обращаться к bot.edit_message_text А у меня его нет Так как я нахожусь в файле handlers С router = Router()
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from get_kb import get_kb
import config

router = Router()
@router.message(CommandStart())
async def start_bot(msg: Message):
    await msg.answer(text=config.greeting_text)
    await bot.edit_message_text(text='111', message_id=msg.message_id + 1, chat_id=msg.chat.id) # Вот здесь ошибка Так как обьекта бот нету


Вы можете дернуть объект бота у объекта Message
msg.bot.edit_message_text

Спасибо, я уже год пытался решить сам эту проблему Но вы гений !

иногда полезно смотреть, что подсказывает редактор кода :)
